# Why react native opt in flipper version is always below the flipper most recent released version

Tags: react-native, fbflipper

I am using `react native 63.4` in my recent project. Because I'm not sure how many inconsistencies may be in new versions due to the big changes after 63.x.

I'm trying to use **Flipper** and I know there are issues with different versions even if you don't want to use it.
The thing is in 66.0-rcx release notes says *Update Flipper to 0.99.0 (41f45a77ad by @swrobel)*
Why the don't officially use the latest version which is now 0.109 ? Even for a candidate release